# How to get the Local IP of an ASP.net site when each site running on IIS is assigned its own IP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have 2 asp.net websites running on IIS with each has its own IP assigned to it. During the processing of one aspx page on let's say site 1, I make an HttpWebRequest to another aspx page by using **HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri** and replacing the page with the desired page. I get a socket exception. During my research, I realized that cisco doesn't let http request to be generated for internal resource by using my external IP address. I need to replace host name in **HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri** with the local ip address assigned to site 1. I don't want to hard code local ip address. Is there a way to get the local address that the site binds to using C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "local address" (perhaps the NETBIOS name or some internal server FQDN) your SSL cert won't match and you'll get an error.

The best thing you can do is go onto the box that is running IIS and add a [hosts entry](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) so that your site's external FQDN will resolve to 127.0.0.1. This will bypass DNS, bypass the network, and still work with the site's SSL certificate.

^ Assumes you are not using a particular type of SSL offloading (re-encryption with secondary cert).

Comment: I have to do this for both sites. If it always resolves to 127.0.0.1, then how would it know which site is meant for the request?

Comment: Go to IIS and inspect the bindings for the two web sites.  Are they bound to separate IP addresses?  If so, use those instead.  Maybe do a quick telnet check to make sure they are accessible locally.

Comment: I already did that. It works with the binding IP, but request times out which is a separate problem.

Comment: Are you saying it works now, or are you asking for help with the timeout issue?

Comment: Because of timeout issue, I can't say it works. Using binding IP helps with socket exception that I was getting. The thing is on my local environment, it all works. Then put on UAT server and getting request timed out. The only difference is UAT uses https.

Comment: Could be it is doing a [CRL check](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/964.certificate-revocation-list-crl-verification-an-application-choice.aspx).  If it doesn't allow outbound then it would time out.  You can turn it off temporarily to see if the fixes the timeout.